# How to convert date to local language in RDLC report

Tags: c#, rdlc

anyone knows how to convert date into localize format in RDLC report ? I've already set Language and NumaralVariant property gu-IN and 3 respectively but it display date as like '23-10-2013' instead "૨૦/૧૦/૨૦૧૩".

Is there any property I have to set for this ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I want to display RDLC report in Gujarati language including I also want to display date in Gujarati.

Comment: aa answer dekhu chhu tame??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427535/report-rdlc-localization-globalization?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: aare ganda bhayy,, work howe chhe ki nathi?

Comment: no this is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427535/report-rdlc-localization-globalization?answertab=active#tab-top aa answer ma baddhhi steps follow karu chhu?

Comment: ha badha step follow karu 6u pan date always 23-10-2013 na format ma j ave 6.

Comment: bhay aa answer dekhe chee to jara http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709082/localization-of-reporting-services-reports-rdl-rdlc-files?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39815/discussion-between-sandy-and-third-battle-of-panipat)